# How to deliver sqlite driver to the end user?

Tags: qt, sqlite, driver

My program written in Qt C++ calls the sqlite database. On my own computer it works good, but on the end user's computer it says "Driver not loaded". True, I don't know which files/dlls should be copied/installed,

can you please help me?

Update: I found I need to copy sqlite3.dll, sqlite3.def and sqlite3.exe into windows/system32 folder OR the folder of my program but it still cannot load database.

OS is Windows xP.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to copy `qsqlite4.dll` (or `qsqlite4d.dll`, if you are distributing a debug build) from your `$QTDIR\plugins\sqldrivers` folder to a `sqldrivers` subfolder in your program folder. Qt should then be able to pick it up from there, if you don't use anything special...

Comment: This didn't work for me. I copied the file into the *same* directory as the executable and then it worked.

Answer (score 5):

Please read the [Windows deployment guide](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/deployment-windows.html), plugins section. You are not supposed to drop things in `windows\system32`, there's a specific directory structure to follow. The exact paths depend on your Qt installation and your application path.

Comment: Yes, the problem was exactly with plugins. Thanks

Comment: @Mar, your link has broken for a long time, and Valentin suggested a fix. Why don't you unbreak your link?

Comment: @Final: I guess I missed the comment.