# Create a Replica of Oracle DB table in local sqlite3 db

Tags: c++, sql, qt, qt4

I am writing a GUI application using QT - C++ which will create a replica of a Oracle DB table in my local sqlite3 DB.

Till now all I am capable to do is replicate the Oracle DB table in that Oracle DB itself--

```
void MainWindow::on_replicate_button_clicked()
{
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QOCI");
    db.setHostName("oracle.db.ip.address");
    db.setDatabaseName("dbname");
    db.setUserName("uid");
    db.setPassword("pwd");
    db.setPort(port);
    db.open();

    QString query_to_replicate;
    query_to_replicate=QString("CREATE TABLE %1 AS %2").arg("REPLICA_TABLE").arg(ui->lineEdit->text());    //The name of replicated table is REPLICA_TABLE and the original table's name is taken input via lineEdit
    QSqlQuery query_second(query_to_replicate,db); 

    if (query_second.lastError().isValid())
    {
        qDebug() <<QDateTime::currentDateTime()<<"TABLE NOT REPLICATED "<< query_second.lastError().text(); 
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << QDateTime::currentDateTime()<<"Table created successfully ";
    }
}
```

thus, I am able to create a replica of a table in Oracle DB (whose name is taken input from lineEdit) and save it as "REPLICA_TABLE" in the Oracle DB itself.

But later, when I am trying to connect to the local sqlite3 DB and do the replication, but after invoking the connect option and running the program, it shows an error when I press the replication push button;

QDateTime("Thu Dec 11 16:41:44 2014") Oracle Query FAILURE  "Driver not loaded Driver not loaded"

If I remove the sqlite3 database connection lines,

```
QSqlDatabase dbsqlite = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
dbsqlite.setDatabaseName("/home/aj/source_db.db");
dbsqlite.open();
```

Then there are no errors and my program becomes useless.

So what strategy should I use to make a copy of the original oracle DB table in a local sqlite3 db table ??? Is it possible to establish multiple DB connections and working on them in the same function module ???

Comment: You error has nothing to do with the replication but only that you can't connect to your `sqlite` db. Do you have the library available? [This could be useful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6326274/how-to-deliver-sqlite-driver-to-the-end-user)

Comment: yes I have the library. I have worked on and connected to several sqlite db s before from the same machine. And I have taken all the adequate driver declarations in program also.